# Reading partially RAW files or TIFF files without loading the full file

Tags: image, processing, tiff

High community and thank you for the answers I have already found !

I would like to know if there is a way to load as an array a piece of a picture in TIFF format or ideally in RAW format directly from the hard drive without to have to load the full file in RAM.

I need to process a very large amount of file (around 2500) but only need a few pixels of each.

I am new to programing and essentially use Processing, I wrote a program that work with small files but I need to built high res picture to be able to print them in large format. So I would like short the time of process.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Around 2500 what? pixels? MB? If you need to work with impossibly large files, you're probably going to have to first write a java program for selectively loading pixels from a TIFF file (effectively writing a TIFF decoder yourself) and then turn that into a Processing library so you can use it in your Processing program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I meant 2500 files, I wrote a program that picks the pixels I need in the file but I have to load the entire file in the RAM before. I wondered if we could access to the pixels directly on the HD without to load the entire file and so save a lot of time of process. So yes writing a tiff decoder, I will have some search on that....